# Slider responsive on load, but not on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, responsive-design

I'm using the [Moving Boxes](http://css-tricks.com/moving-boxes/) plugin, and have adapted it to be a full-width image slider. It's responsive on load, but I'm having trouble getting it to respond on resize too. It seems like the widths become fixed to a specific value on load (by the JS), and the percentage widths defined in the CSS no longer apply.

Any help would be appreciated, as I can't write JS yet. Thanks in advance!

[Testing site](http://rockodzn.com/testing3)

CSS:

```
.slider {
    width: 100%;
}

.slider li {
    width: 80%;
}

.mb-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    width:100% !important;
    top: 0;
}

/* Panel Wrapper */
.mb-slider, .mb-scroll {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

/*** Slider panel ***/
.mb-slider .mb-panel {
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}

.mb-panel.current img {
    opacity:1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

/*** Inside the panel ***/
.mb-inside {
    width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.mb-inside img {
    width:100%;
    opacity:0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.mb-inside * {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

JS that generates widths (assuming from the notes). Full JS file temporarily linked [here](http://rockodzn.com/testing3/js/jquery.movingboxes.js).

```
 // defaults
                base.$window = base.$el.parent(); // mb-scroll
                base.$wrap = base.$window.parent() // mb-wrapper
                    .prepend('<a class="mb-scrollButtons mb-left"></a>')
                    .append('<a class="mb-scrollButtons mb-right"></a><div class="mb-left-shadow"></div><div class="mb-right-shadow"></div>');

                base.$panels = base.$el.children().addClass('mb-panel');
                base.runTime = $('.mb-slider').index(base.$el) + 1; // Get index (run time) of this slider on the page
                base.regex = new RegExp('slider' + base.runTime + '=(\\d+)', 'i'); // hash tag regex

                base.initialized = false;
                base.currentlyMoving = false;
                base.curPanel = (o.initAnimation) ? 1 : base.getHash() || o.startPanel;
                // save original slider width
                base.width = (o.width) ? parseInt(o.width,10) : base.$el.width();
                // save panel width, o.panelWidth originally a fraction (0.5 of o.width) if defined, or get first panel width
                // now can be set after initialization to resize using fraction (value <= 2) or px (all values > 2)
                base.pWidth = (o.panelWidth) ? (o.panelWidth <=2 ? o.panelWidth * base.width : o.panelWidth) : base.$panels.eq(0).width();
```

There is a part of the JS file where you can change certain options. In the bottom of these options it says this:

```
// deprecated options - but still used to keep the plugin backwards compatible
// and allow resizing the overall width and panel width dynamically (i.e. on window resize)
// width        : '100%',       // overall width of movingBoxes 
// panelWidth   : 0.8        // current panel width adjusted to 80% of overall width
```

When I un-grey 'width' and 'panel-width' and apply values I get strange results. Can elaborate if needed. It could be that some of my CSS is conflicting with how these options are handled in the JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following code

```
$(function(){
    $('.slider').movingBoxes({
        startPanel   : 1,      // start with this panel
        wrap         : false,  // if true, the panel will infinitely loop
        buildNav     : false,  // if true, navigation links will be added
        navFormatter : function(){ return "&#9679;"; }
    });
});

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    $('.slider').movingBoxes();
});
```

I didn't test it but I think it should work. If not, you can experiment with different parameters passed to `movingBoxes` method. The plugin itself is initialized this way:

```
$.fn.movingBoxes = function(options, callback, flag){
    var mb;
    return this.each(function(){
        mb = $(this).data('movingBoxes');
        // initialize the slider but prevent multiple initializations
        if ((typeof(options)).match('object|undefined')){
            if (mb && options instanceof $ && options.length) {
                // pass a jQuery object to change panels
                mb.change(options, callback, flag);
            } else if (mb) {
                mb.update(callback, flag);
            } else {
                (new $.movingBoxes(this, options));
            }
        } else if (mb) {
            // page #, autoplay, one time callback, if flag is false then no events triggered and animation time = 0
            mb.change(options, callback, flag);
        }
    });
};
```

All the problem we're facing here is the duplication of `movingBoxes` instance. E.g. The object inits onload. Then you resize the window and the question is if the object will be only updated (desired behaviour) or it will create second instance which may cause unpredictible behaviour. Comments in the code suggest it wont' be initialized multiple times.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. It makes sense to call the same function on resize, but it isn’t working unfortunately (currently uploaded [here](http://rockodzn.com/testing3/) ).

I came across something unexpected. It happens when I remove the function which calls it on load, and keep it called on resize. So on resize it loads the JS as soon as you start resizing, but immediately afterwards, stops being responsive. (currently uploaded [here](http://rockodzn.com/testing2/) )

It seems like as soon as the JS is loaded, the width values written in the CSS are overwritten by the JS with fixed values.

Comment: I managed to use this:
`var timer;
  $(window).resize(function(){
   clearTimeout(timer);
   var slider = $('.slider').data('movingBoxes');
   slider.options.width = $(window).width() * 1; // make 100% browser width
   slider.options.panelWidth = 0.8; // make 80% of wrapper width
   // prevent updating continuously, aka throttle resize
   timer = setTimeout(function(){
    slider.update(false);
   }, 100);
  });`
to load the function on resize, but it's only applying it to the first slider, not the others. Class names are all the same. Any ideas?

Comment: When you're calling `$('.slider').data('movingBoxes')` the selector _picks up_ all elements with `.slider` class but `jQuery.data` function is called on the first one only. I'd suggest wrapping all the operations with `jQuery.each` and define `timer` as an array. See the whole code [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/w8eEN/). It won't work in the fiddle obviously but I put it there just to make it more readable.